# How to set android facebook sdk 3.5 locale to arabic?

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I am using facebook sdk 3.5 for facebook sharing.How can i set the locale of facebook sdk to arabic manually.? I am changing the app locale to arabic and when changing the locale back to english , the facebook sdk remains as the arabic. How to change it manually?

Comment: Are you referring to results from Graph API requests, or visuals/strings provided by the SDK (like the login button)? For Graph API requests, the locale is controlled on the server side, and will be the language that the user specifies in their profile. For SDK strings, you should provide your own translations of the strings in the strings.xml file.

Comment: Hi Ming Li,thanks for the reply.I am using the sdk WebDialog for sharing. When i change the app locale from arabic to english, the WebDialog doesn't change the locale. It remains as arabic.How can i change the arabic locale of webdialogue manually to english.?